# Passing C# 'string' in C++ dll as 'Char*'

Tags: c#, c++, .net

Hi I have create c++ function as

```
void MyClass::GetPRM(BSTR BString)
{
//----
}
```

In C# the dll interface looks like:

```
GetPRM(char* BString)
```

My question is how can I pass string as char* from c# to c++ dll?
I have tried doing 
`void MyClass::GetPRM(std::string BString)` but no luck.
Any Suggestions

Comment: A C# interface would use String, not char*.

Comment: when trying to call c++ dll from c# function; the parameter datatype is 'char*'

Comment: It would be if the C++ function were also taking char*.  Your C++ function takes a BSTR, which is a pointer to a string of 16-bit wchar_t characters, not 8-bit chars.

Comment: Are you trying to call a C# function from C++, or are you trying to call a C++ function from C#?  Either way, you probably need a "C" function, not C++, to interop with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
 [DllImport("mycppdll", EntryPoint="MyClass_GetPRM")]
 extern static void GetPRM([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string BString)
```

However, that doesn't take into account C++ name-mangling, nor your C++ method's `this` pointer if that method is not declared static.

On the C side, you may need a wrapper function like this:

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall
 MyClass_GetPRM(BSTR BString)
 {
     MyClass::GetPRM(BString);
 }
```

which would require adaptation of the C# declaration to match the exported name:

```
 [DllImport("mycppdll", EntryPoint="MyClass_GetPRM")]
 extern static void GetPRM([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string BString)
```